# external storage table already exists error datajoint matlab

Tags: matlab, datajoint

Whenever I want to create a table with multiple external storage fields I get the following error:

```
Table '~external_behavior_time_spatial_blobs' already exists
```

This is a code snippet of the table I am trying to declare:

```
%{
-> acquisition.Session
-> behavior.TowersSession
---

iteration_matrix:           blob@behavior_time_spatial_blobs   # block-trial-iteration reference matrix
trial_time:                 blob@behavior_time_spatial_blobs   # time series of this trial, start from zero for each trial
cumulative_session_time:    blob@behavior_time_spatial_blobs   # time series of this trial, start from last trial time
collision:                  blob@behavior_time_spatial_blobs   # boolean vector indicating whether the subject hit the maze on each time point
position:                   blob@behavior_time_spatial_blobs   # 3d recording of the position of the mouse, length equals to interations
velocity:                   blob@behavior_time_spatial_blobs   # 3d recording of the velocity of the mouse, length equals to interations
sensor_dots:                blob@behavior_time_spatial_blobs   # raw recordings of the ball
%}

classdef SpatialTimeBlobs < dj.Imported
```

When I define the table with a single blob field, it is created without errors.

Comment: There is no question in your post. Ask a specific question, like why does this happen or how do I work around this.

Comment: The original poster privately reported that removing underscores made this table structure possible: `blob@behavior_time_spatial_blobs` --> `blob@behaviortimespatialblobs`. This is likely not an intended behavior of DataJoint matlab, and may be a byproduct of how attributes are encoded on the backend